# problems with admob migration

Tags: android, admob

Recently I have migrated from old admob to new admob (google play service). Everything ok, The Android app loads the banner add in the first layout (Frame Layout). But only blank space appears in other Layouts. I am using Frame Layout with Tabhost.

I used the below code

```
adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("356d6707MydiviceID")
        .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in an app. In my case the adview was blank until the activity was resumed (for example when the screen switched off and on again). I solved it simply by setting the background of the adview (I didn't have the adview in xml, so I added it programmaticaly):

```
...
layout.addView(adView, adParams);
adView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
...
```

you can use any other color. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's enough room for the ad to be displayed. Check in both portrait and landscape mode. Also check the ad's "layout_width" and the banner type. Try using a "SMART_BANNER". If it fails, try setting the adView's background to transparent or black to see if that works:

```
adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```